# how to define tokenizing rules

Tags: python, regex

I want to tokenize strings like:

```
'my name.is(johnny ,knoxville):'
```

into:

```
['my', 'name', '.', 'is', '(johnny ,knoxville)', ':']
```

As you can notice, whitespace separates tokens, non-alphanumeric chars are not grouped with alphanumeric chars, and there's another exception:
Everything enclosed in parenthesis is taken as a whole token.

I'm not sure if I should use python RE, some python module I don't know about or an external lib like `pyparsing`

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you should also consider `nltk`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
from re import findall

input = 'my name.is(johnny ,knoxville):\nmore\n;'
results = findall(r'(?:[(][^)]*[)])|\w+|\S', input)
print results
```

Produces the result:

```
['my', 'name', '.', 'is', '(johnny ,knoxville)', ':', 'more', ';']
```

Comment: What does that `(?:` mean?
I've read about it in the official docs, but I don't understand what it does.

Comment: You can divide a regex into groups with (...) and then only those groups will be returned in the answer. By using (?:...) the content is still grouped, but it will not be returned in the answer. The reason a group is needed is so it becomes group|group and not lastPartOfTheGroup|group. If (...)|(...)|(...) and not (?:...)|(?:...)|(?:...), the input 'my (name)' will return [('', 'my', ''),('(name)', '', '')] and not ['my', '(name)']

Comment: Thanks so much!!!! That lastPartOfTheGroup|group intuitive line made me understand it. I'm thinking about making it a question/answer on SO.